# Number of distinct prime divisors of three consecutive numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\omega(n)$ be the number of distinct prime divisors of $n>1$. I could prove that: there are  infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $\omega(n+1)+\omega(n-1)>2\omega(n)$. Similarly, the reverse inequalities also hold for infinitely many positive integers.

I wish to study the case $\omega(n+1)+\omega(n-1)=2\omega(n)$. Is this equation has infinitely many solution in $\mathbb Z^+$? For example n=3.

Comment: Can you show your claimed proof that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $\omega(n+1)+\omega(n-1)<2\omega(n)$?

Comment: @quasi I think one way is via [Chen primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_prime): there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is a product of $\leq 2$ primes. Then for $p>4$
$$\omega(p)+\omega(p+2)\leq 3 < 4 \leq 2\omega(p+1)$$

Comment: Ok, but that's not an elementary result. Not that it has to be, but the fact that the only proof you alluded to uses such a result suggests that your question is, most likely, a research-level question.

Comment: There are large examples : $10^{50}+34,35,36$ all have $5$ distinct prime factors, so $\color\red {10^{50}+35}$ is an example.

Comment: How to see that $10^{50}+34$ has 5 distinct prime factors, Peter?

Comment: @quasi : I prove as following: If not, set $g(n)=\omega(n+1)-\omega(n)$, then $g(n)\ge g(n-1)$ for any $n\ge n_0$, where $n_0$ is an integer. Let $n_1=4^{2^k}-1$ then $g(n_1)>0$ (since $g(n_1)$ has two prime divisors $3,5$. On the other hand, let $n_2=2^{3^m}+1$ then $g(n_2)\ge0$. Thus $g(n_1)<g(n_2)$. But we may chose $n_2<n_1$, this contracts the assumption.

Comment: @Jie Fan: Nice! Although presumably you meant: "then $g(n_1)<0$ (since $n_1$ has two prime divisors $3,5$)".

Comment: @JieFan $10^{50}+34 = 2\cdot 71 \cdot 932927137 \cdot 910427319766973 \cdot 829122399559467938971027$. I imagine it was from a search starting from $10^{50}+1$, since that is the first number to yield a solution. The expected number of distinct factors is about $\log\log N$ which is $\approx 4.75$ for $10^{50}<N<2\cdot 10^{50}$, so I suppose it's not unreasonable to hope for solutions to your equation since there are so many candidates with the same expected distinct prime factors. Another example is $\omega(\{10^{60}+39,10^{60}+40,10^{60}+41\})=\{4,5,6\}$.